# How to change the default loading icon in a Python flet app?

Tags: python, web-applications, icons

I am building a graphical user interface using [`flet`](https://flet.dev/) in python.

However, I am stuck with the default `flet` logo

[image: this logo]

while loading the app in the browser viewer, and I don't see any hints about changing it in the documentation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a folder in your root directory named `assets`.

Inside place your logo named `favicon.png`

Finally, point `flet` to your `assets` folder

```py
flet.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets", view=flet.WEB_BROWSER)
```

> Additionally, check [here](https://github.com/flet-dev/examples/tree/main/python/apps/custom-loading-image) how to add your own manifest

**UPDATE:**
Check [this](https://flet.dev/blog/packaging-desktop-apps-with-custom-icon/) article if you want to make an executable with pyinstaller and add a custom icon. Previously, to do this, required some dirty tricks (replace the flet icon inside the .exe file).

It seems like now it's as easy as

```
flet pack your_program.py --icon <your-image.png>
```

[link](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/packaging-desktop-app/#customizing-package-icon) to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

@Panos Stavrianos

It works and without even `manifest.json` file, but not with all ports.

With:

```
flet.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets", port=#####, view=flet.WEB_BROWSER)
```

on my box, my personal favicon strangely doesn't work when port is between 41556 and 41559.

Comment: Consider adding as a comment on the other answer rather than creating a dependent answer

Comment: I tried, but the link told me "You must have 50 reputation to comment"